# how to enable preview after selecting picture from library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I am trying to write an app which involves picking a picture from either camera or library. Once the picture is picked , I want to show the preview of the picture.It happens by default when camera is opted. Once the photo is clicked, it shows the user to choose or retake. But I want the same to be done when the picture is selected from the photo library also. Can this be done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks for the response. Here is what I did:
Subclass UIImagePickerController . Upon picking an image, I am pushing another viewcontroller which is similiar to preview screen. This is similiar to facebook app and so I think it will get approved by apple.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I think you need to implement the custom view yourself. You can use the [delegate callback method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069) to get the selected image and put it on your custom view along with buttons (choose or retake).

Comment: I like this idea of getting a separate delegate method but I implemented as below.